# Apache 2.2.15 responds status 44 when uploading some type of pdf file

Tags: apache

There are some problems with uploading some type of pdf files. Below are entries from access_log. First one is with pdf file with size of 8.9 MB and it succeeds. The other one is pdf file with size of 1.8 MB. I tried to rename last one to exclude some kind of filename length issues but with no success.

```
[05/Nov/2019:21:09:23 +0200] "POST /Content/Upload HTTP/1.1" 200 77 "http://www.example.com/url-removed" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"
[05/Nov/2019:21:09:31 +0200] "POST /Content/Upload HTTP/1.1" 44 525 "http://www.example.com/url-removed" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"
```

Can't find that status code in documentation to see what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow managed to change configuration so that this error got logged. Turns out it was caused by ModSecurity rule MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY.
Error message I got:

```
[Tue Nov 12 14:02:28 2019] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 44 (phase 2). Match of "eq 0" against "MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY" required. [file "/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf"] [line "39"] [id "200003"] [msg "Multipart parser detected a possible unmatched boundary."] [hostname "example.com"] [uri "/Content/Upload"] [unique_id "XcqfVAoKCgwAAA7PLhwAAAAH"]
```

Comment: What did you change in the configuration ? Did you remove the line in `mod_security.conf` ?

Comment: This is what I have now in my mod_securty.conf file:
`SecRule MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY "!@eq 0" \  
"id:'200003',phase:2,t:none,log,allow,status:44,msg:'Multipart parser detected a possible unmatched boundary.'"`